# ORA-00918 returns from stored procedure but it works executing a query in SQL Page

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying return a list from db but it gives me Error "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined".

When I execute this query inside new SQL page, **it returns true list**. However, when I write it in a package as stored procedure, it returns ORA-00918 and package goes invalid status.

What is the reason for this difference?

```
select distinct c.customer_no, m.title, c.group_id, g.name, c.pricelist_id, p.name from db.customer c
join db.pricelist p on c.pricelist_id = p.pricelist_id
join db.master m on c.customer_no = m.customer_no
join db.group g on c.group_id = g.id
where (c.customer_no = pn_customer_no  or pn_customer_no=-1)
and (c.group_id = pn_group_no  or pn_group_no=-1)
and (c.pricelist_id = pn_pricelist_no  or pn_pricelist_no=-1)
and (c.kom_type = ps_kom_tip)
order by c.customer_no asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New SQL page assigns your dublicate columns new temporary column names.
But stored procedures add your values a list matched column names.
Therefore, two columns have same names, it confuses which name should desired name.
Like bundle, your column name will be key to learn value and value will be value.
You should change one of them p.name or g.name or both of them.

```
select distinct c.customer_no, m.isim_unvan, c.group_id, g.name as groupName, c.pricelist_id, p.name as tarifeName from db.customer c
join db.pricelist p on c.pricelist_id = p.pricelist_id
join db.master m on c.customer_no = m.musteri_no
join db.group g on c.group_id = g.id
where (c.customer_no = pn_customer_no  or pn_customer_no=-1)
and (c.group_id = pn_group_no  or pn_group_no=-1)
and (c.pricelist_id = pn_pricelist_no  or pn_pricelist_no=-1)
and (c.kom_type = ps_kom_tip)
order by c.customer_no asc
```

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting the columns:

```
select distinct
       c.customer_no,
       m.title,
       c.group_id,
       g.name,           -- NAME column
       c.pricelist_id,
       p.name            -- NAME column
```

When you run the query in SQL/Plus or SQL Developer (or another IDE) it will output the columns:

```
CUSTOMER_NO TITLE GROUP_ID NAME PRICELIST_ID NAME1
```

and will rename the second `NAME` column to `NAME1`.

In the PL/SQL scope, it will not do this and will try to handle the two columns with the names you have given (i.e. the same names), fail and return `ORA-00918`.

You need to give one (or both) column an alias so they have distinct names.